# Kuldevi for Narvekar family of Kitte Bhandari caste in Rajapur, Ratnagiri

Tags: kula-devata

Can anyone tell me the Kuldevi of Narvekar, Kitte Bhandari caste living in Rajapur, Ratnagiri?

We went to that village and the grandmother said आपली देवी ही वाघावरची देवी ("Our Kuldevi is one who sites on a tiger"), and we are now confused as to which Shantadurga sitting on a tiger it is that she's referring to. There are many different Shantadurga in Goa, so can anyone give me some clear details??